# Dynamic Meta tags shows on first load but disappear on page reload (NuxtJs 2.8.1)

Tags: nuxt.js, meta-tags

When first time product page loads, it shows proper meta tags but if we reload it again then meta tags disappears. Also if we only change pages as transitions without page reload then it works fine.
Nuxtjs version 2.8.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nuxt doesn't have `v2.8.2`.

Try updating to latest version of nuxt or go with atleast Nuxt `v2.9.0/v2.9.1`
where they updated `vue-meta to 2.0.0.`

Which should resolve issue.

Comment: I have updated to 2.11.0 which resolved the issue. Now meta tags does not disappear but showing data-n-head="ssr" in all tags. Is it ok?
also my open meta tags (og:image, og:url etc) are not getting detected by facebook debugger or any other meta tag checker
http://joxi.ru/D2P5YYBFk4L18A